# JDiskReport is damaged, can't be opened

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-space

I have tried downloading and running JDiskReport 1.4 a few times now, and after unzipping it and clicking on the executable I get the message:

```
"JDiskReport" is damaged and can't be opened.  You should move it to the Trash
```

Why is it not working?  I'm running 10.8 Mountain Lion on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried this myself and confirmed that the executable gives the error you mentioned:

```
"JDiskReport" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash.
```

I was able to get it to run setup by Ctrl-clicking JDiskReport.app, clicking `Show Package Contents` and navigating to Contents/Resources/Java/jdskreport-1.4.0.jar.  Ctrl-clicking this .jar file will allow you to click Open and bypass Mountain Lion's default 'unidentified developer' error.  I did not go completely through Setup (only confirmed that it ran), so try this and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above, `Show Package Contents...` will also fix an `'Unable to load Java Runtime Environment.'` on OS X Mavericks with Version 1.4.1 of JDiskReport. Sorry but I can't upvote or comment yet.