# "Minecraft" is damaged and can't be opened on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, applications, java, zip

I'm trying to run Minecraft on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I downloaded the zip file (link [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/Minecraft.zip)) from [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net/download) and unzipped it. Double clicked on the icon and it tells me,

> "Minecraft" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the
>   Trash.

I've downloaded it several times and 2 other unzipping tools don't complain. Is it some issue with Mountain Lion? I have Java installed with versions as follows:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

***UPDATE***: I did the Show Package Contents for minecraft and ran the JavaLauncher on the jar file, seemed to work. But after minecraft updated itself, I got this error:

```
      Minecraft has crashed!      
      ----------------------      

Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem; Failed to start game

A full error report has been saved to /Users/scott/Library/Application Support/minecraft/crash-reports/crash-2012-11-25_10.25.30-client.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :(



--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT 99374f70 --------
Full report at:
/Users/scott/Library/Application Support/minecraft/crash-reports/crash-2012-11-25_10.25.30-client.txt
Please show that file to Mojang, NOT just this screen!

Generated 11/25/12 10:25 AM

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.4.5
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.8.2
    Java Version: 1.7.0_09, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 22467144 bytes (21 MB) / 71499776 bytes (68 MB) up to 1060700160 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    LWJGL: 2.4.2
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null[failed to get system properties (java.lang.NullPointerException)]


org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not get the JAWT interface
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndInitHandle(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.access$100(AWTSurfaceLock.java:49)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock$1.run(AWTSurfaceLock.java:89)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.privilegedLockAndInitHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:86)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTSurfaceLock.lockAndGetHandle(AWTSurfaceLock.java:64)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXCanvasPeerInfo.initHandle(MacOSXCanvasPeerInfo.java:53)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplayPeerInfo.doLockAndInitHandle(MacOSXDisplayPeerInfo.java:56)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.PeerInfo.lockAndGetHandle(PeerInfo.java:85)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXContextImplementation.create(MacOSXContextImplementation.java:47)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Context.<init>(Context.java:120)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:858)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:232)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:515)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
--- END ERROR REPORT adc22a49 ----------
```

Comment: Just tested.  Same problem here.

Comment: hm. that's seemingly related to [the question I answered a while ago](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/jdiskreport-is-damaged-cant-be-opened/62327). @Nathan 's suggestion about damaged application files seems plausible.

Comment: All of these no longer work. This now works, running from terminal: xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/minecraft.app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem actually was that Mountain Lion gives this nonsensical error message to any app not authorized by Apple or from the App Store, by default. You just have to go to Apple -> System Preferences... -> Security & Privacy -> Allow applications downloaded from:

Then select "Anywhere". Seems like this is useful, but I couldn't get Minecraft to run without disabling this security check.

Comment: Once you've run Minecraft, you can set the Allow apps setting back.  The OS will remember that MC is okay to run, and you maintain the security benefits for any unsigned apps you open for the first time.

Comment: What a stupid error message!  If it had said "This installer isn't from a trusted source" or "This isntaller is not authorized" I would have been able to figure out what was going on for myself.  The fact the little snitch installer worked on Lion but not Mountain Lion and threw this daft error threw me totally.

Comment: 'The JavaApplicationStub provided in Mountain Lion (and Lion?) is signed by Apple, but once it is bundled into a developers own App, that signature becomes invalid. So, if a Java developer chooses to ignore signing, they instead get a "damaged" app that produces a message like "This app is damaged, moved it to the Trash" and there is no way to run it.' http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jul/msg00136.html

Comment: You don't see the "damaged" message for every unauthorized app; it seems to be a problem with the way some Java apps are signed. Mountain Lion describes other unauthorized apps correctly as from an unidentified developer or not from the App Store. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290

Comment: This helped me fix EVE online for Mac too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.

One workaround is to right-click on the file, select Show Package Contents, then go to Contents -> Resources -> Java.  Then, just open using MinecraftLauncher.jar.  You can make an alias to this for easy access if you want.

I'm guessing that something is damaged/wrong with one of the application files in the Minecraft.app file.

Comment: Updated my question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

The java app works fine for me, but launchers can be fragile on OS X. You could try this Minecraft launcher I coded in bash since it would explicitly call java rather than relying on the system to call it:

http://pastebin.com/NEcagTvW

The package is called bashcraft and [the source is available on github](https://github.com/Qwertylex/bashcraft).

```
#!/bin/bash
# bashcraft, a minimal Minecraft launcher and updater
# crafted by Alex (Qwertylex), Zarek Jenkinson (akiwiguy) and maybe some more
# see https://github.com/Qwertylex/bashcraft/blob/master/README.md for details
# License: This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
# To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
```