# How can developers properly fix "App is damaged and can't be opened" errors?

Tags: macos, homebrew, development, third-party

There are already [several](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/372084/2643) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58086/2643) [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72609/2643) on this site dealing with the error message "$App is damaged and can't be opened". The workaround given (which has worked for me) is to use `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine` on the affected app package.

The developers of [LaTeXDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net), a small open source tool, state that hints about solving this would be welcome. LaTeXDraw shows the problem when installed through their DMG image, as well as through Homebrew. It seems this is a rather old piece of academic software primarily used and developed on Linux, which they just build along for macOS as well, so I would like to help them out.

I thought the "proper" solution to this is just to become a registered developer -- is that correct and sufficient? What is the technical cause of this (very confusingly worded) message, i.e. what would need to be changed in the app package?

Comment: Not a definite answer but it looks like distributing through the mac app store or becoming an identified developer would help: The wording for default security settings on my mac is "Allow apps downloaded from... -> Mac App Store and identified developers".

Comment: I believe that the application needs to be 'signed' at the very least and probably 'notarized' as well, but I can't say for sure so I won't offer this as a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer needs to make sure their application is notarized.

The official documentation on how to do that is available here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution

In order to get the application notarized, it must first be signed.

The developer can choose to use their existing binary and get it notarized "after the fact" (instead of during build using Xcode). You would then take the final binary and upload it to Apple using `notarytool` (comes with Xcode). When the developer gets the ticket back, it can be attached to the binary using the `stapler` tool.

The process is documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow#3087734

Comment: many thanks for this reply. Due to personal reasons, I wasn't able to award the bounty in time. Let me know if you know of a way I can do this in retrospect. -- With regard to your answer: How would this work for binaries built locally, e.g. with Homebrew or Macports?

Comment: I don't know if you can start a new bounty for the question now - perhaps? ... Regarding binaries built locally - there would be no problem with those, as they aren't downloaded and thus not quarantined